# Android : On Notification bar dismiss, view gets resized under status bar. How to disable the resizing?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Here's my activity scenario.
[image]

1 - shows my activity layout, with image stretch across the view

2,3 - On drop down of the notification bar, the imageview gets resized to the status bar size

4,5 - On dismissing the notification bar (dragging up), the imageview has a white gap on the top (height equals status bar height), and then suddenly jumps to full screen.

The activity has flags SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY set.

Tried many settings and combinations, but no solutions has been found yet.

Any solutions for removing this resizing of the imageview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally playing with many options, I finally found a workaround.

in **onWindowFocusChanged** added the flags to the window,  **FLAG_FULLSCREEN** and clear Flag **FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN**.

this avoids the activity being resized when notification bar gets dragged down.

Any better solutions are welcome.